# JavaSparkStreaming | Exception thrown in awaitResult

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm a new bee using java spark-streaming api to read from kafka topic. 
Piece of code written:

```
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster(args[4]).setAppName("JavaKafkaWordCount");

        // Create the context with 2 seconds batch size
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(1000));

        int numThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        Map<String, Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<>();
        String[] topics = args[2].split(",");
        for (String topic: topics) {
            topicMap.put(topic, numThreads);
        }

        JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages =
                KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, args[0], args[1], topicMap);
```

command to run:

```
./bin/spark-class -jar ../runnable/spark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  localhost:9092 "" incoming 1 spark://localhost:7077
```

Then throws the following exception:

```
16/10/31 11:50:05 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://localhost:7077...
16/10/31 11:50:05 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to localhost:7077 after 28 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
16/10/31 11:50:05 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master localhost:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anonfun$tryRegisterAllMasters$1$$anon$1.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:109)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RequestMessage; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -2221986757032131007, local class serialVersionUID = -5447855329526097695
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:616)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$deserialize$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:259)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:308)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$deserialize$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:258)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.internalReceive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:578)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:563)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:159)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:107)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:119)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.handle(TransportResponseHandler.java:190)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:121)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        ... 1 more
```

It connects but disconnects, what exactly does that mean? I dont think there is version missmatch.
pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0-beta1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                    <artifactId>avro-mapred</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>chill_2.10</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>chill-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <!-- <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
                </exclusion> -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
                    <artifactId>json4s-jackson_2.10</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.10</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0-M4</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency> <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId> <artifactId>storm-hdfs</artifactId> 
            <version>0.10.0-beta1</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId> 
            <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId> <version>5.3.1</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Building using sharde plugin:

```
<build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>org.labs.analytics.spark.streaming.StreamingKafkaConsumer</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include> **/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

Please suggest a VM provided with spark, kafka, mongoDb, Zookeeper.

Comment: Your cluster is running Spark 2.0 compiled against which Scala version? It could be that your Spark binaries are compiled against 2.11 but you used 2.10 in your code.

Comment: Tried using scala library for 2.10 and 2.11. But it continued to throw same exception.

Answer (score 0):

That was an issue with versions mismatch of.Scala from spark(installed) against library's used. 
I have considered re-installing 2.0.1 spark, scala-2.11.4 and the pom.xml as below:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```